# How do you pass bearer token without using page url in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have an ASP.NET MVC application based on the default Visual Studio SPA template. After a user successfully logs in, javascript reloads the page to call the OAuth authorize endpoint using this url

```
window.location = "/Account/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);
```

Here is the server side code that handles bearer tokens

```
        PublicClientId = "web";

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/Authorize"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

The OAuth authorize endpoint responds with a 302 redirect with the access token in the url such as

https://example.com/#access_token=wKB_9sVptsGr...

Javascript extracts the token from the redirect url and uses that to authenticate with WebApi. This works beautifully as it allows us to be authenticated on both MVC side and WebApi side. However, this method of returning bearer tokens was identified as an issue during a recent cyber-security audit since the token is stored in the browser history exposing the `access_token` to other users.

Is there a better way to return a bearer token? We need both the MVC and the WebApi parts to be authenticated.

**EDIT**

Just to clear things up, this question is about the **first time the server passes the access token to the browser**. Not the browser passing the token back to the server.

Comment: you can use the headers.....

Comment: @Claies, can you elaborate?

Comment: Plenty of articles that talk about using headers for authentication, both here and on the wider web.  Have you done any sort of research?

Comment: even the official microsoft documentation shows both using headers and using the request body to hold token data.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Comment: Of course I've done plenty of research. You obviously didn't understand the question. I'm not asking about how to pass the bearer token to the server. I do that already by setting the request headers. The question is about when the server returns an access token for the first time to the browser.

Comment: Why downvote a perfectly valid question if you don't understand the subject? The above comments are irrelevant as they are answering questions I never asked. See edits for clarity!

Comment: This works if you create a header and set the Authorization bearer token. But what about GET requests? Suppose we have a image element that points to a URL like **<img src="/download/{some_id}>**. How can you pass the token in the URL and use the **[Authorize]** attribute?